# how to read data from excel sheet and store it into a user defined variable

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have created a code to modify a date by adding specific no of days into it by using a variable name Date.
Now i am having several texts including several different dates in excel sheet which i want to read then modify and again rewrite into same excel sheet.

For this i have created a code but i am not able to load the data read from excel sheet to a variable.

please suggest and provide a code/query how to read data from excel sheet and store it into a user defined variable

Comment: Take a moment and take a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link.

Comment: You can directly work on Activesheets cells. This routine should be useful to you. ~
Sub test_add()
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:C").Cells
    c.Value = CDate(c.Value) + 5
    Next c
End Sub

Answer (score 2):

Try this example
values are stored in rowData variable

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\VBScriptTrainee\Teams.xlsx")
objExcel.visible=True

rowCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count
colCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.count

Msgbox("Number of Rows are    " & rowCount)
Msgbox("Number of columns are " & colCount)

intRow = 1
intCol = 1
rowData=null


  for intRow=1 to rowCount  step 1


    for intCol=1 to colCount step 1 

       rowData = rowData & " " & objExcel.Cells(intRow, intCol).Value

    next

       rowData = rowData & vbnewline

  next


Msgbox(rowData)

objExcel.Quit
set objExcel=nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have dates in excel in the single column with column name as 
're-data'. We can take out sample code using ADO connection string. Here is the sample VBS code.

```
filelocation = "D:\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"
SheetName = "Sheet1"
column_name = "re_data"
row_number = 8

'Create connection
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'Create Record Set
Set recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'Connection String
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filelocation & ";Extended Properties = Excel 12.0 Macro;"
On Error Resume Next
'Connection Open
conn.Open
query   = "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & SheetName & "$] "
recordset.Open query, conn, 3, 3


Count = 1
Do Until recordset.EOF Or Count = row_number
Output_variable =  recordset.Fields.Item(column_name).Value
recordset.MoveNext
Count = Count + 1
Loop

MsgBox Output_variable
recordset.Close
conn.Close
```

Comment: Above code take out 8th row elecment in 're-data' column. hope this solves this problem.